Installing ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server on pythonanywhere
I am using Google Cloud SQL for a telegram bot and apart from all the pip installations like
pyTelgramBotAPI, pyodbc, requests, I need the ODBC Driver for it to work. Since, I did not find any possible ways to do it with the bash console I do not know what else to do.
Is there any possible ways to connect this driver to pythonanywhere hosting service or not?
I have done everything needed apart from installing the driver on this hosting service.
It is the last part remaining and I want to know if I can do something about that!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
